# How to use onclick function on button. When Button has no ID and Name, it only has class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this question in my Javascript exam. So i have to use JS to solve this problem

How can i use onclick function on button, as there is no id and name.

So in this code can i use document.getelementsbyclass ? or which is better ? and how to use document.getelementsbyclass or any other function to retrieve and store onclick button data

`button type="submit" height="40px" color="white" class="Button1">` span Let's GO span button

Thank you

I haven't tried anything because i don't know the proper coding. I am on my self-taught research phase.

```
<button type="submit" height="40px" color="white" class="Button1"><span>Let's GO</span></button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.querySelector`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".Button1"))
```

```html
<button type="submit" height="40px" color="white" class="Button1"><span>Let's GO</span></button>
```

`onclick` you can pass the element itself to a function using `this` keyword

```js
function a(ele)
{
console.log(ele)
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" height="40px" color="white" class="Button1" onclick="a(this)"><span>Let's GO</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can call it by `getElementsByClassName` 
as `getElementsByClassName` returns a array of elements so you have to set the index number of an element. Then you can call the `addEventListener`

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('Button1')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
   console.log('ok')
})
```

```html
<button type="submit" height="40px" color="white" class="Button1">
   <span>Let's GO</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.getElementsByClassName` method to retrieve your element in the DOM. Unlike `getElementById` this method will return an array, since there could be more than one element in the page with the same class. If you only have one button with that className you can then do `document.getElementsByClassName('Button1')[0]`.

Another similar method is `document.querySelector` that takes a CSS selector string as argument and will return the first occurrence of an element matching that selector (if any). `document.querySelector('.Button1')`

Answer (score 0):

```
it will work

 <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Button1").click(function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });

    });
</script>

<button type="submit" style="height:40px; color:white;"  class="Button1"><span>Let's GO</span></button>
```